# Why training is smoother when no randomization of batch after each epochs is applied?

Tags: neural-networks, stochastic-gradient-descent, random-allocation

I am wondering why training error converges more smoothly when I am not applying randomization after each epochs?

After each epoch I am taking the loss obtained in my last minibatch. I see that when using no randomization this loss is decreasing monotonously. Contrarily when using randomization I see a convergence in mean but with higher variance.

Since I am updating parameters through gradient descent after N-1 batches I would expect slight variation on the loss for the last minibatch. How optimizing on N-1 minibatches never lead to a loss increase of the last minibatch? Even if the data is not changing, the parameters are updated for 1 minibatch at a time and since each minibatch is slightly different from the one another I would expect a decrease of the loss of the last minibatch in mean but not monotonously.

Would somebody has an intuition on this ?

Thanks